# On Hover CSS3 Shadow Gets Darker

Tags: html, css, shadow

I have added an overlay of shadow on my images but I want the shadow to get darker when I hover the image. I tried a bunch of different things but I couldn't get it to work properly and it would shift the pictures all over the place when you would hover. This is what I have so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qf4Ka/6/

**HTML**

```
<section id="top-container" class="top-column" style="width:1050px; height:400px; ">
   <div class="image" style="float:left;">
      <img src="http://www.hdwallpapersinn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/HD-Wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" border="0"; width="263"; height="200" style="display: block; border-top: 1px solid #dddddd; border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd; border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;">
      <h4 style="font-size:30px; top: 90px; ">Nature</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="image" style="float:left;">
      <img src="http://www.hdwallpapersart.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/tiger_wallpapers_hd_Bengal_Tiger_hd_wallpaper1.jpg" border="0"; width="262"; height="200" style="display: block; border-top: 1px solid #dddddd; border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd; ">
      <h4 style="font-size:30px; top: 90px;">Bengal Tiger</h4>
   </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.image {
    position: relative;
}

h4 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: "Oswald";
    text-align: center;
    max-height: auto;
    z-index: 20;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
    -moz-text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
    -ms-text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
    -o-text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
    -webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
}

.image {
    position: relative;
}

.image:before {
    content: '';
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px 4px #000 inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 50px 4px #000 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 50px 6px #000 inset;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 20;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to remove jsFiddle links from all your questions? You've done this a second time after I reverted your changes the first time around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `transition` to the `:before` pseudo element.

```
.image:before {
    transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition:all 1s;
}
```

Change the pseudo element's `box-shadow` on `hover` of the `.image` element.

```
.image:hover:before {
    box-shadow:0 0 100px 30px #000 inset;
}
```

Here is the [**updated example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hcm5J/).

Comment: If I add the :hover before the :before that will remove the shadow that's on the image if you are not hovering over the image. I want that little shadow to stay there and when you hover over the image, it makes the shadow even darker. So basically I want that little shadow to stay even if you are not hovering over the image.

Comment: @CusaJohn Alright - misunderstood. I thought you wanted it to be displayed on hover.